# VB.NET Service Skipping Over Sub Procedure

Tags: vb.net, service, vb.net-2010

I'm writing a Windows Service in VB using Visual Studio 2010. The service is going to check for changes to a table in a database every minute or so. I have experience with VB6 but am new to both VB.NET and creating services, so I might be overlooking something obvious here. When the service is stopped, paused, started, or resumed, a sub procedure is supposed to be called. The problem is that the program skips right over the call to the sub procedure. I set break points at OnPause() and OnContinue() and stepped through the code, to confirm that the program is skipping right over the calls to AgentStopped() and AgentStarted(). What am I doing wrong?

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPause()
    Log.WriteEntry("Agent paused.") 'This is written to the log
    AgentStopped() 'This line is skipped
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnContinue()
    Log.WriteEntry("Agent restarted.") 'This is written to the log
    AgentStarted() 'This line is skipped
End Sub

Private Sub AgentStarted()
    Log.WriteEntry("AgentStarted called.") 'This never written to the log
End Sub

Private Sub AgentStopped()
    Log.WriteEntry("AgentStopped called.") 'This never written to the log
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you understand, **there is no way for the lines you imply to be skipped since the containing method is called**. Something else is happening. I suppose the code you are showing is simplified. Right?

I would bet that either you are running a wrong version of your code by mistake, or on your real code an exception occurs inside the called methods (`AgentStarted` and `AgentStopped`).

In order to debug this, I would follow these steps:

- Change the current log messages and add messages after the call to the functions

  Protected Overrides Sub OnPause()
      Log.WriteEntry("Agent pause beginning.")
      AgentStopped()
      Log.WriteEntry("Agent pause ending.")
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnContinue()
      Log.WriteEntry("Agent restart beginning.")
      AgentStarted()
      Log.WriteEntry("Agent restart ending.")
  End Sub

  If you see the new messages, you will be able to verify that you are actually **running the right version of the code and not an older version deployed by mistake.**
- You should use exception handling with `try - catch`. I am not really sure (I have never used it), but perhaps using the [UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event to get info for possible uncaught exceptions could be helpful. Another option would be to check the [windows event log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for errors occuring while executing a web service.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I did add try-catch statements and checked the Windows event log and found nothing. Then I rebuilt the project again, without changing anything, and it worked. I have no explanation.. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: For some reason, you were running the wrong version of your code. Please upvote my answer. It is important for users navigating to your question to be able to identify the helpful answers...

Comment: I can't upvote yet. I'm new and I don't have enough reputation. I will as soon as I'm able.